# to update in ng-rpeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to update username in ng-repeat directive. I am able to edit if I take a variable but unable to do so in an array. Here `title` is a variable and `users` is an array. I want to update a user's name

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
      {{title}}  {{name}}

      <br>users
     <ul> <li ng-repeat="(key,u) in users">
    {{key+1}} name: {{u.name}}  <a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor(u.name)">Edit title</a>
         </li></ul>

    </div>
    <div ng-show="editorEnabled">
      <input ng-model="editableTitle" ng-show="editorEnabled"><br><br>
     <input ng-model="editableUserName" ng-show="editorEnabled">

      <a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>
      or
      <a href="#" ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Welcome to this demo!";

     $scope.users = [{'name':'A'},{'name':'B'}];

  $scope.editorEnabled = false;

  $scope.enableEditor = function(name) {
      $scope.editorEnabled = true;
    alert(name);
    $scope.editableTitle = $scope.title;

     $scope.editableUserName = name

  };

  $scope.disableEditor = function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.title = $scope.editableTitle;
   $scope.users.name = $scope.editableUserName;
    $scope.disableEditor();
  };
}
</script>`


`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd like to have an id which doesn't change that associates to each user.

This plunker is your answer [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9iGyLcqcFdjsqtHWXQYo?p=info)

I have gone and used the $index of the array as an id, but ideally you should give each user an id

```
ng-click="enableEditor($index)"
```

I have also altered some of your functions to record the index

Comment: Thanks Yang Li. Now my concern is while editing one name the others are hidden. I want them to be displayed while i am editing any one of the name

Also after editing and updating the updated name is not saved to my array 'users'

Comment: No worries, is this another question you are asking? I'm not exactly sure what it is you are having an issue with.

Comment: Yes this is another question

Like there is name 'A' when I edit it , I cant see name 'B' .

Comment: Also when I rename A to abc it is printed abc but my array still saves this name as A

Answer (score 1):

For the edit pass in the user you are editing:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor(u)">Edit title</a>
```

Then store a reference to that user.

```
var editableUser;

$scope.enableEditor = function(user) {
    $scope.editorEnabled = true;
    $scope.editableTitle = $scope.title;

    $scope.editableUserName = user.name;
    editableUser = user;
};
```

Then in the save, save the changes to the user:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.title = $scope.editableTitle;
    editableUser.name = $scope.editableUserName;
    $scope.disableEditor();
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2VZk2Ej6DR4g51MjiC3j?p=preview

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Take a look at the plunkr and compare the code.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I missed to include the app.js file in my folder before running the html file. The is is solved now.